# How to use tax_query other than by slug or id or solve custom taxonomy tags conflicts with pre-existing tags?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, taxonomy, tax-query

I just encountered a problem and realized that all tags must be globally unique.

Here is what just happened to me:

I created a taxonomy called `writer` and added each author and collaborator to the post they have written or/and collaborated to. For this, I was getting `post id as the $object_id` and `user nicename as the $term` for the `wp_set_object_terms` function.

After filling up my new taxonomy with the writters, I wanted to display a list of posts using WP_Query and tax_query. The arguments for the tax_query would be as follows:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'writer',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $array_of_nicenames
    )
)
```

So each item in the array would be matched against the taxonomy slug.

Everything was working fine until I hit and already created slug. Thus, the writer slug would read `user_nicename-2` instead of `user_nicename`. The post made by this user would not be displayed on my list.

I hope I am making myself clear; otherwise, ask me to clearify anything.

I was thinking about using the user id instead of the user nicename; however, eventually I would come up with the same problem. For example, I could have a tag called 2003 and a user with the same id.

A *possible solution* I came up with but I would like to avoid is this one:
For each new user, create a meta tag that would include the user nicename attached to a preffix like this `uniquepreffix-user_nicename`, thus incrementing my chances to have a really unique username/slug for later use.

Is there any other way I can accomplish what I want without encountering this problem?
Can I use tax_query by name instead of slug?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you are doing but my feeling is that you are using taxonomies incorrectly. You shouldn't ever need to create a duplicate.

Comment: @s_ha_dum my problem is similar to this one: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/how-can-i-resolve-name-collisions-between-custom-taxonomies